# Using TLE data how would I create a KML file to look at a particular spot at a particular time

Tags: google-earth-engine, kml, google-earth, google

Let's say I have some TLE data as follows:

```
REDACT
1 13337U 98067A   20087.38052801 -.00000452  00000-0  00000+0 0  9995
2 13337  51.6460  33.2488 0005270  61.9928  83.3154 15.48919755219337
```

I wish to view, for example, the Washington monument on 1st June 2019 14:00

I'd want this in a KML file so I can import into Google Earth Pro.

Any advice?

**CLEARING UP**

1. This is a competition at work over this holiday weekend
2. I have a KML file and I essentially need to fill in the blanks under NetworkLink > Link
3. I have the TLE information above
4. An image was captured from that satellite that shows a picture at a specific lat/lng at a specific time
5. I presume I have to see what position that satellite was at that specific time and then plug in the relevant files into the KML file (as below)

[image]

```
<viewFormat>BBOX=[bboxWest],[bboxSouth],[bboxEast],[bboxNorth];CAMERA=[Long],[Lat],[lookatRange],[lookatTilt],[lookatHeading];VIEW=[horizFov],[vertFov],[horizPixels],[vertPixels],[terrainEnabled]</viewFormat>
```

Comment: TLEs describe the orbit of a satellite, but the Washington Monument is fixed on the ground. Could you clarify what you hope to achieve by using the TLE? (It wouldn't be needed for using satellite imagery datasets, which usually have ground location (georeferencing) already prepared.) And are you specifically looking to use Google Earth Engine (which is a separate platform from Google Earth)?

Comment: Have amended the question to hopefully be more clear